# Are there any Android Camera components I could reuse / buy instead of coding from scratch?

Tags: android, camera

I am in the middle of building my Camera based app for Android. I base my work on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html and I do believe that handling all the Camera.Preferences has been done 100 times already and dozens of developers went through the path of

1. Check if the Flash is there
2. Check what are the Flash modes supported
3. Show those modes using fancy icons so user can select what she/he wants.
4. ... and ... and ... and ... handle resolution differences for preview and final image
5. ... and ... and ... and select what scene settings should be used ...
6. (which is closer to step 66) Finally, when you have all the user selections made - do take a photo, process data[] and take another one if you want

Rather than reinventing the wheel again (mine will be a semi-square one) I tried to find a component that will handle the UI piece and let me play with the takePhoto() and handle data[] coming from the camera when I need it.

After failing to find that ... I realized that in general I have problems finding components that one could reuse for free or buy for Android development.

So there are really two questions.

1. Are there any well established **Camera components** I can reuse for free or buy and add to my Android project.
2. What are the **stores with components** for Android development? Where / How to Google for them?

Thanks in advance for any help provided. Have a great weekend Folks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described why you are trying to write a new camera app. The simplest way to reuse the existing camera features is to use an intent. You basically call up the existing camera application and have it return you a photo.

[Android documentation for intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents)

Comment: I do want to make few photos and access the image of data[] level rather than make a single photo.

Comment: The intent allows you to capture a single photo and return that photo to your application. The interface for taking the photo is identical to that used in the standard camera application. Once you get the photo back, it is up to your application to process it as you want.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-receive